# PHP - CodeIgniter ¿Como pasar variables a 2 view pero cargar solo una de ellas?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actualmente los arrays(variables) los envió correctamente a una view, pero resulta que esta es una modal y quiero que las variables lleguen también a la view principal(esta segunda sin cargarla, solo que se almacenen temporalmente en ella).

Aquí el código que funciona correctamente con una sola view:

```
$proyeccion = $this -> data['proyeccion'] = $this -> cnm_liquidacioncuotas -> CnmCalcularCuotasVista($datos, $fecha_activacion, $medio_pago, $hipotecario, $reliquidacion, $refinanciacion);

$this -> data['seguros_vida'] = $this -> cnm_calculosegurosvi -> calculoSegurosVida($datos, $proyeccion);

$this -> data['seguros_incendio'] = $this -> cnm_calculosegurosvi -> calculoSegurosIncendio($datos, $proyeccion);

if ($hipotecario == 'true')
    {
      $this -> load -> view('carteranomisional/carteranomisional_visualizar_proyeccion', $this -> data);          
    }
```

Reitero nuevamente, el envió a esta view se hace correctamente con los arrays **$this -> data[]**. Pero quiero enviar los mismos a una segunda view sin la función **$this -> load -> view()**, puesto que esta me carga nuevamente otra pagina, lo cual no es correcto.

Comment: para que quieres cargar variables a una vista q no se va a renderisar? (es uso de memoria y procesamiento. Lo que puedes hacer en dado caso es `$view_hidden = $this->load->view('otherview', $this->data, TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

En este caso te recomendaría que uses peticiones Ajax, así podrás traer la data cada vez que las necesites.
Aquí un ejemplo de como usar ajax y codeigniter.

https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-jquery-ajax-post/